# Сортировка с помощью Stream api

Tags: java

```
    package src;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class API
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\user13\\Desktop\\text.txt")).useDelimiter("[^a-zA-Z]+");
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        while (scanner.hasNext())
        {
            String word = scanner.next();
            if (map.containsKey(word))
            {
                map.put(word, map.get(word)+1);
            }
            else
            {
                map.put(word, 1);
            }
        }

        List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entries = new ArrayList<Entry<String,Integer>>( map.entrySet());

        Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> a, Map.Entry<String, Integer> b) {
                return a.getValue().compareTo(b.getValue());
            }
        });

        for(int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(entries.get(entries.size() - i - 1 ).getKey()+" = "+entries.get(entries.size() - i - 1 ).getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, переписать программу, чтобы сортировать с помощью STREAM API

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entries = map.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```